# How to truncate any spaces to just one space?

Tags: php

I have this field for entering car numbers, like `AS 1234 10`. I want a php code that can keep reduce the space to just one if in case user is to add more spaces. So like if he enters `AS  1234  10`, then it automatically truncates it to the original `AS 1234 10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to replace multiple spaces by a single whitespace:

```
preg_replace("/[[:space:]]+/"," ",$input);
```

See a [live demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1cae29a8a1881d8ad735ab3681de5342ab4f9603).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$text = 'AS  1234  3       1';
echo preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $text);
```